# How to use nextLink property in azure pagination in /providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines REST API

Tags: azure, pagination, azure-virtual-machine

I am calling azure `/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines` REST API. I need to implement pagination for this API. As per Azure docs `Use the nextLink property in the response to get the next page of virtual machines.` nextLink property is `The URI to fetch the next page of VMs. Call ListNext() with this URI to fetch the next page of Virtual Machines.`
I am not using Azure SDK for making azure REST calls.
Do I need to set the authentication header for this URI?
How the URI will look like?

Answer (score 2):

`nextLink` property is a URL that you receive if the server sends a partial response for your request.

For example, let's say you have 100 VMs in your Azure Subscription and when you try to list the VMs, the response only contains information about 50 VMs. Along with that response, you will get `nextLink` property using which you can fetch next 50 VMs.

It looks almost identical to your original request URL but it will have a `$skiptoken` query string parameter.

For example, if your original request URL looks something like:

`https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines?api-version=2021-03-01`

then your `nextLink` would look something like:

`https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines?api-version=2021-03-01&$skiptoken=<somevalue>`.

You would still need to add authorization header to your request.

Please note that `$skiptoken` is an opaque value and you should not try to infer its meaning or define any business rules on its value. If you get `nextLink` in the response, then it would simply mean there's more data available on the server.

Comment: Is there a way to limit the response size. I used query para $top but looks like it does not work with /providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines REST API. I want to test the pagination as for now I am not getting nextLink property set because there are only 10 virtual machines in my test environment.

Comment: Ideally $top should work but I’ve seen inconsistencies in the way REST APIs have been implemented for each resource provider.

Comment: GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/<subscription>/resourceGroups/<resource-group>/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines?api-version=2021-03-01&%24top=2

Sample Response:
{
  "error": {
    "code": "BadRequest",
    "message": "The request URL is not valid."
  }
}

Comment: I'm also getting a 502 status code back when I specify `$top` in the request. I don't think it is supported here. You can try to use [`List Resources`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/resources/list) operation and filter the results there. It supports `$top`.

Comment: For example, try this request: `https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/<your-subscription-id>/resources?$filter=resourceType eq 'Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines'&api-version=2021-04-01&$top=1`

Answer (score 0):

An example piece of code would be:

```
req = requests.get("https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines?api-version=2021-03-01", headers=headers)
total = [] #list to store all the values
c = 0 #counter variable I use for visibility 
while 'nextLink' in json.loads(req.text):
    total.extend(json.loads(req.text)['value'])
    req = requests.get(json.loads(req.text)['nextLink'], headers=headers)
    c+=1
    print(c, len(total))
```

With a word - just passing the 'nextLink' value to the while loop as long there is a 'nextLink' in the response.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you do need to use Authentication header (like for any REST call you make to Azure REST services). You need a bearer token which you can acquire based on type of user you are using (User, Service Principal or Managed Identity).

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth-ropc
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow

**nextLink** property is just URI which you will need to append to the baseURL/hostname used in previous call. I do not see a reason why should you be interested in what exactly the value of nextLink is.

So for example if you are making initial call to

```
https://management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines
```

which will provide **nextLink** property in the response. With this **nextLink** string you should make the following call

```
https://management.azure.com/{nextLink}
```

and you should repeat the nextLink call logic as long as the nextLink property is present in the response.

And once more authentication bearer token is required for each call.